# does calling alloc_page count against process?

Tags: linux-device-driver

I am experimenting with a linux device driver on allocating physical memory/pages. I have a single ioctl, which any application can call, which simply allocates a physical page and maps it to process memory using vm_insert_page. I am using alloc_page() to allocate a physical page.
What i want to know is if the physical page allocated by alloc_page() is counted against the process making the IOCTL or if it is simply a physical page that belongs to the driver.

The counting i am referring to is in things like low memory killer in android or the out of memory killer. These components keep track of physical memory usage by a process before deciding what process to kill in a low memory or out of memory situation.

Another question: What is the difference between GFP_HIGHUSER and GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE? I understand using alloc_page(GFP_HIGHUSER) will give me a non-pageable(not swapped to disk) page. does GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE change this ? Kindly dont point me to the source. I am asking this question because the source as i have seen this and it has insufficient documentation or i fail to understand from the documentation provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `alloc_pages()` allocates `(1<<order)` contiguous physical pages, hence it is a physical page that belongs in Kernel-space, hence belong to the driver, and the zone where it resides is dependent on Zone Modifiers that you pass. And that is why We must be careful to free only the pages we have allocated. Passing the wrong struct page or address, or the incorrect order, can result in corruption. Its more like the kernel trusts itself. Unlike user-space, the kernel happily hangs itself if we do something horrid.

Comment: If you agree and satisfied with the answer, may be you could just accept it as an answer

Comment: Not yet satisfied. What if i use the flag GFP_HIGHUSER? WHat happens then ? Does you answer still hold good?

Comment: Consider a situation where the requirement as that a hotpluggable node that only allows `__GFP_MOVABLE` allocations in the zonelists. This would probably involving having one zone that only allowed `__GFP_MOVABLE`. As I have read from a source, `__GFP_MOVABLE` Flag says that this page will be movable by the page migration mechanism or reclaimed.
This is node hotplug and we already have a node/zone structure etc where we could set some option to require only movable allocations.

Comment: IS the migration between different NUMA nodes ? You would only need that in linux servers right?